# Déjà Dup Backup failed to execute child process “duplicity” (No such file or directory) Ubuntu Mate 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: 18.04, apt, backup, deja-dup, duplicity

Since today I get the Déjà Dup error mentioned in the title. I'm aware that there are a lot of questions about this error. Sadly, the answers given there won't work for me because:

- `sudo apt-get install duplicity` leads to

  > duplicity is already the newest version (0.7.17-0ubuntu1.1)
- `sudo apt-get install python-gi` leads to

  > python-gi is already the newest version (3.26.1-2ubuntu1)
- `sudo apt-get install deja-dup-backend-gvfs` leads to

  > Unable to locate package deja-dup-backend-gvfs

Also `sudo apt update` with `sudo apt upgrade`, `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and `sudo apt full-upgrade` does not solve anything.

Therefore none of the previous thready could solve my problem. I would be pleased if someone could help me to fix that. I will provide you any information you need.

---

```
$ which duplicity
/usr/bin/duplicity

$ duplicity --version 
/usr/bin/duplicity: /usr/bin/python2: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is the output of `which duplicity` and `duplicity --version`?

Comment: Yes, of course, you have to reinstall Python 2 by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-minimal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have also try to reinstall these packages with [`duplicity` executable](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=duplicity) by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall duplicity deja-dup
```

if their files were corrupted.

Your Python 2 installation is corrupted, you can get `/usr/bin/python2` back by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-minimal
```

Comment: I pasted the code and it reinstalled the packages but unfortunately the error is still present.

Comment: Reinstalling Python 2 did it for me. Thanks a lot!